# From Windows 7/10 how do I low level an old harddrive for inclusion into a RAID-1

Tags: windows

I have a system using 2 drives as a RAID-1, I want to take one out as a backup but replace with another recently formatted drive. How do I format the drive ?

Comment: This is not a security question

Comment: The raid controller will format the drive before including it in the array or rebuilding the array.

Comment: What have you tried? All you should have to do is plug the drive in and use the RAID controller to set it up.